# Detecting trash from aerial photographs of parks?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm currently working on a project which requires the use of a drone to detect trash in a park. However, my background in machine learning/image processing is very minimal, to say the least, so I'm not sure exactly where to start.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by gathering and annotating the images with trash and then training your ml model to identify trash from those images

for dataset you can refer to https://github.com/spotgarbage/spotgarbage-GINI

try looking at transfer learning, you can use https://github.com/garythung/trashnet as a source for your base model or further dataset

start by training simple ml algorithms like svm and then you can try cnn for a better accuracy

Answer (score -1):

At [Picterra](https://picterra.ch/) we provides a tool that allows to build your own AI object detector on drone images without requiring any background in machine learning.

The principle is the following:

-fly your drone and acquire your images

-Upload your image(s) on the platform (The best would be to upload orthomosaics generated with a professional photogrammetry software like Pix4D or DroneDeploy but raw images might also work)

-Show some examples of the objects you want to detect (buildings in the picture below but this could be applied to trash or any kind of object you are interested in) 
[Example of buildings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O0nI.png)

-Automatically detect all the similar objects 
[Buildings detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwCmc.png)

You can iterate of couple of times to perfect the output of the detector.